# Understand post type

Tags: posts, theme-development, post-type

I am a bit lost, even after searching answers qutie everywhere..
I am creating a theme for Wordpress, and I would like to have three custom post types (gallery, audio and video). So I added the support into the theme:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'video', 'audio' ) );
```

But then what? I can choose via a radio button when I create a post which one I want to use but where do I put the meta?

I want to display a video. where do I put the video URL? same for audio and gallery.

Is there an easy way to add control depending of the custom type?

Comment: `gallery, audio and video` that you used are not custom post types, they are custom `post formats`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing things a bit, these are post **formats**, not post **types**.

Formats are a native *taxonomy*, not a post type. As any taxonomy its primary (and only) functionality is to organize posts in logical groups.

Formats don't do *anything* on top of that. You need to implement yourself *any and all* functionality you want your posts with Format assigned.

This takes custom code in your theme (often with some custom fields framework as helper).

Comment: A note on the templates available for individual post formats would be super useful here, perhaps a link to some of Justin Tadlocks stuff

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, do you have a link of tuto or whatever to help me to implement the 3 differents post format I want?

Comment: Looking at how core themes do it might be a good start. I hadn't seen that much material on it because it was never really very successful feature and since it's almost entirely up to theme the implementations are pretty arbitrary.